# I'm trying to do filtering on my data which which I'm getting from my child component as checkbox to the parent component but how to do

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs

here this is my code which I used for filtering the data on basis of priorities as (low, medium, high)

priorityArr is the variable I'm using to store the filtered data one after one , which i'm originally getting from "this.data"

the below code is from my parent component for which "prio" is the variable which is getting data from the child component

using the following code I'm getting data successfully on the console but can't able to display on the screen and how do I use the "filter" operator from "rxjs" for this purpose

```
priorityArr:any;
  //used for checkbox filtering purpose
  selectedCheckBoxFilter(prio:any){
    console.log('demo --> ',prio)
    console.log("prioLevel parent ",prio.priorityLevel)

      console.log("priority array -->",this.priorityArr);
      for(let i=0;i<this.data.length;i++){
        if(this.data[i].priority==prio.priorityLevel){
          if(prio.canEnable){
            console.log(this.data[i]);
            this.priorityArr.push(this.data[i])
          }
        }
      }

  }
```

prio.priorityLevel is the value, and prio.canEnable is just to check whether the check box is active or not
my actual data is in json array like format

```
this.priorityArr.push(this.data[i])
```

using this line I cant able to push and I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
```

Comment: can't you do a filter on your data like this `this.data = this.data.filter(dataItem=> priorityArr.includes(dataItem.priority))` this will check for every item if your dataItems priority is present in the priority array and only return the data where this is the case

Comment: the solution to your question is defined the priorityArray as empty array:`priorityArr:any[]=[]` (the `=[]`). But use [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RxJs filter operator is not used to filter arrays, it is used to allow the stream to emit values that pass the filter function. If you want to filter arrays you use the filter method on the array itself.

```
selectedCheckBoxFilter(prio:any){
  this.priorityArr = this.data.filter(d => d.priority === prio.priorityLevel);
}
```

This returns a new array with the elements that pass the filter function.

If you have an observable that emits an array and you want to filter values in the emitted array you use the RxJs map operation to emit a new array that is filtered by the array's filter function

```
arrayObservable$.pipe(
  map(array => array.filter(item => trueToKeepFalseToDiscard))
)
```